DAX measure that enables me to switch between fiscal year and financial year
I want to create power bi DAX measure that enables me to switch between fiscal year and financial year using my sales data
Total Credit Card Spending by Year = 
VAR YearType = SELECTEDVALUE('Year Type'[Year Type], "Calendar Year")
RETURN 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    YearType = "Calendar Year", 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('Credit Card'[Line Amount]), 
            VALUE(RIGHT('Calendar'[Calendar Year], 4)) = YEAR(TODAY())
        ),
    YearType = "Fiscal Year", 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('Credit Card'[Line Amount]), 
            VALUE(RIGHT('Calendar'[Fiscal Year], 4)) = YEAR(TODAY())
        )
)


could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
